# Providing custom package name for debian package created using "stdeb"

Tags: linux, package, debian, stdeb

I am trying to create a debian package using the below tool.

[astraw/stdeb](https://github.com/astraw/stdeb#bdist-deb-distutils-command)

I am able to create the package with default name as specified in the site. I need to provide custom name. "--package" is the option that we need to use. Issue is , though I see the deb package created with the custom name, it also has some junk values added. Ex:

> novadocker_0.0.1~dev205-20151105_all.deb

Here

> novadocker is the --packagename and 20151105 is the --debian-version.

I am not sure about how to remove other values in between [_0.0.1~dev205-]

Command that I used to create this is :

```
python setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command sdist_dsc --package novadocker --debian-version 20151105 bdist_deb
```

Any way to fix this ?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `--debian-version 20151105`?

Comment: I get novadocker_0.0.1~dev205-1_all.deb

Comment: for me python is coming in the beginning everytime. any idea?